# Extracting columns of text from a rectangular string

Tags: string-manipulation

I have *very large* rectangular strings (on the order of 30-100 MB in size), which I import into Mathematica from text files using a command like `text = Import["test.txt", "String"];`.  A small representative example string `str` is below.  Lines of text in the rectangular strings are delimited by the `"\n"` character.  I would like to write an *efficient* function that extracts columns of text from the string.  It must be efficient because my actual strings are so large.

It seems that splitting the string into individual characters, using something like `Map[Characters, StringSplit[str, "\n"]]`, is not an option, because it seems to take too much memory.  So, in `takeFun` below, I have instead located the positions of characters in each column.  Can you think of a more efficient way to write `takeFun`?  By efficient, I am referring to memory conservation, not speed.  Thank you!

```
str = 
"ABCDE
abcde
12345";

pos = Prepend[StringPosition[str, "\n"][[All, 1]], 0];

(* Define a new string take function *)
takeFun[s_, p_, index_] := StringTake[s, Partition[p + index, 1]]

(* Take first column *)
takeFun[str, pos, 1]

(* Take second column *)
takeFun[str, pos, 2]

(* Take fifth column *)
takeFun[str, pos, 5]
```

which gives this output:

> {"A", "a", "1"}
>
> {"B", "b", "2"}
>
> {"E", "e", "5"}

Comment: Have you considered using `"Table"` instead of `"String"`, or even [`ReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReadList.html)?

Comment: Andrew, I updated my answer to describe a methodology that I believe will be of value to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### General method

Since the emphasis of this question is on performance I propose something like this:

```
extractColumn[file_, col_] :=
 Module[{bin, len},
   bin = BinaryReadList @ file;
   len = 1 + LengthWhile[bin, # =!= 10 &];
   bin[[col ;;;; len]] // FromCharacterCode
 ]
```

Or, if you prefer, condensed:

```
extractColumn[file_, col_] :=
  FromCharacterCode @
    #[[col ;;;; 1 + LengthWhile[#, # =!= 10 &]]] & @ 
      BinaryReadList @ file
```

This directly reads in the text file as 8-bit integers; it would be possible to use 16-bit integers if the file uses. 16-bit encoding.  It then finds a line return (`10`) to determine line length, and extracts the column with `Part` and `Span`; finally the output string is reconstructed with `FromCharacterCode`.

To test it I make a 44MB rectangular text file `"textblock.txt"`:

```
Export["textblock.txt",
 Riffle[
   StringJoin /@ RandomChoice["a"~CharacterRange~"z", {500000, 90}],
   "\n"
 ] // StringJoin
]
```

Then call:

```
extractColumn["textblock.txt", 17] // StringLength // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.406, 500000}
> ```

---

### Methodology for binary data

In a comment you state:

> My text files are files containing only " ", "o", and return
>   characters ("\r" and/or "\n"). The " " and "o" characters comprise an
>   "existence matrix," where " " represents False and "o" represents
>   True. The row number and the column number each have meaning (the row
>   number represents "type" while the column number represents "time"). I
>   would like to sequentially read in each column and perform analysis on
>   each column.
>
> So it would be nice if I could read in multiple columns at once, since
>   I think `BinaryReadList@file` may be relatively expensive (my text files
>   have 200,001 columns each), so calling `extractColumn` 200,001 times
>   (each call taking on the order of 1 second) can be quite time
>   consuming.

Okay, I'll create a new 98MB sample file as follows:

```
Export["TFblock.txt", 
  Riffle[StringJoin /@ RandomChoice[{" ", "o"}, {500, 200000}], "\n"] // StringJoin
]
```

On a modern machine you should be able to read this entire file at once, as strings (using about the same memory):

```
strings = ReadList["TFblock.txt", Record];

ByteCount[strings]

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> 100024032
>
> 115317104

If for some reason this is not possible, e.g. you start working with *huge* files, you could use `Read[stream, Record]` to do this (the following) one row at a time.

**The first rule of working efficiently with binary data is: store it in a binary format.**

Since *Mathematica* is equipped to handle very large integers we can store each row of this data as a single `Integer`.  As strings, each data point takes one byte, but packed in an integer each takes only one *bit*:

```
strings[[1]] // ByteCount
```

> 200040

```
stringToInt = # ~StringReplace~ {" " -> "0", "o" -> "1"} ~FromDigits~ 2 &;

stringToInt @ strings[[1]] // ByteCount
```

> 25040

This operation is a bit slow but with it the entire data is stored in a mere 12.5MB:

```
Timing[ints = stringToInt /@ StringReverse @ strings;]

ByteCount[ints]
```

> {8.627, Null}
>
> 12524032

We can use `BitGet` to pull data from the Integers, indexed from zero at the least significant bit.  (This is the reason for `StringReverse` above.)  This returns the first column: `BitGet[ints, 0]`.  This the last: `BitGet[ints, 199999]`.

The operation is reasonably fast:

```
Do[BitGet[ints, i], {i, 0, 4999}]; // Timing
```

> {0.421, Null}

Confirmation of result:

```
StringJoin[BitGet[ints, 16] /. {0 -> " ", 1 -> "o"}] === 
 extractColumn["TFblock.txt", 17]
```

> True

Of course if the data is always accessed by column it would be better to have the data in that format to begin with.  You could make a one-time pass through the columns using `BitGet` and `FromDigits` to transpose the data:

```
Timing[
 ints2 = Table[ints ~BitGet~ i ~FromDigits~ 2, {i, 0, 199999}];
]
```

> {19.391, Null}

A column is then read with: `IntegerDigits[ints2[[ (*column*) ]], 2, (* row length *)]`.  Row length must be specified so as not to lose leading zeros.  Confirmation:

```
IntegerDigits[ints2[[17]], 2, 500] === BitGet[ints, 16]
```

> True

Data extraction is now very fast:

```
Do[IntegerDigits[ints2[[i]], 2, 500], {i, 1, 5000}] // Timing
```

> {0.016, Null}

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am having some difficulty using `extractColumn`, though. Suppose I have a file called `test.txt` containing the text `ABCDE\nabcde\n12345`.  If I run `extractColumn["test.txt", 1]`, I obtain the output `a1`.  If I run `extractColumn["test.txt", 3]`, I obtain the output `a1` also.  It seems that while `extractColumn` has the header `extractColumn[file_, col_]`, `col_` is not referred to in the function definition.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Andrew sorry, I clearly made a mess of it.  Let me try to fix that...

Comment: Thanks so much. It works great!

Comment: @Andrew you're welcome.  Sorry I wasn't more careful with the copy&paste the first time.  I don't know if you typically need to pull a single column from a file, which is what this is written for, or if you intend to read the file and then pull multiple columns and do other manipulations.

Comment: Thanks. I would *like* to read the file and then pull multiple columns, but in my (novice, limited) experience, I run out of memory on my PC to read the entire file and do manipulations on each column.

Comment: My text files are files containing only `" "`, `"o"`, and return characters (`"\r"` and/or `"\n"`).  The `" "` and `"o"` characters comprise an "existence matrix," where `" "` represents **False** and `"o"` represents **True**.  The row number and the column number each have meaning (the row number represents "**type**" while the column number represents "**time**").  I would like to sequentially read in each column and perform analysis on each column.

Comment: So it would be nice if I could read in multiple columns at once, since I think `BinaryReadList@file` may be relatively expensive (my text files have 200,001 columns each), so calling `extractColumn` 200,001 times (each call taking on the order of 1 second) can be quite time consuming.  Please note that this is *not* a criticism -- your `extractColumn` is *very* fast, and it does not overload the kernel in terms of memory.  I wonder if we could somehow read in multiple -- but not all -- columns at once, perhaps saving some time and still not overloading the kernel in terms of memory.

Comment: Maybe this would be content for another question?

Comment: @Andrew that changes the picture quite a bit.  I don't have time now to update my answer accordingly, but I will.

Comment: Thanks.  There is no rush.  And I am going to accept your answer, anyway.  And probably I should have thought more about this and been clearer in my original question.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
stringColumn[str_String, col_Integer] := Module[{n = StringPosition[str, "\n", 1][[1, 1]]}, 
  StringTake[str, Table[{k n + col}, {k, 0, (StringLength[str] + 1)/n - 1}]]]
```

or

```
stringColumn[str_String, col_Integer] := Module[{n = StringPosition[str, "\n", 1][[1, 1]]}, 
  StringTake[str, {col, StringLength[str] - n + col + 1, n}]]
```

The first one returns a `List[]`, while the second one returns a `String[]`. Take your pick.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to create all the columns in one pass, the following using `Transpose` should work.

```
FromCharacterCode /@ Transpose@(ToCharacterCode /@ StringSplit[str, "\n"])
```

> {"Aa1", "Bb2", "Cc3", "Dd4", "Ee5"}

As per Mr Wizard's suggestion, this can be made more elegant using the listable property of `To/FromCharacterCode`

```
FromCharacterCode @ Transpose @ (ToCharacterCode @ StringSplit[str, "\n"])
```

Comment: I believe that you will find that `ToCharacterCode` and `FromCharacterCode` are Listable, and usually perform better this way: `FromCharacterCode @ Transpose @ (ToCharacterCode @ StringSplit[str, "\n"])`. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative ....

My experience with large files is that `Read` and its ilk work quicker than `Import`, but YMMV.  I'll use the example text "OriginOfSpecies.txt", and I'll assume that it is in the current directory.

```
text = ReadList["OriginOfSpecies.txt", Record] (* automagically break on new line *);
```

Length@text shows we have 758 records.

We can now use `StringTake`.  For example,

```
char01 = StringTake[text, {1, 1}] (* first character from all strings *);
char02 = StringTake[text, {2, 2}];
```

etc,.

Comment: I believe you can shorten this code by using `ReadList` in place of `OpenRead`, `Read`, and `Close`. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, Mr. Wizard and dwa.  I am a little confused, because it seems that `Read[inpu, Record]` reads only the *first* record, not *all* the records.  Is this true?

Comment: @Andrew: Your're correct.  ReadList will read All The Things.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[stringColumn2];
stringColumn2[strng_String, column : {__Integer}] :=
   If[StringLength[#] < Max@Abs@column, "n/A",
      StringTake[#, column]] & /@ StringSplit[strng, "\n"]
```

Usage examples:

```
str2 = "ABCDE 
abcdefgh
12345";

stringColumn2[str2, {3}]
 (* {"C","c","3"} *)
stringColumn2[str2, {2, 3}]
 (* {"BC","bc","23"} *)
stringColumn2[str2, {3, 5}]
 (* {"CDE","cde","345"} *)
stringColumn2[str2, {1, 5, 2}]
 (* {"ACE","ace","135"}  *)
stringColumn2[str2, {-1}]
 (* {" ", "h", "5"} *)
stringColumn2[str2, {-1, -3, -1}]
 (* {" ED","hgf","543"} *)
stringColumn2[str2, {-1, 1, -1}]
 (* {" EDCBA","hgfedcba","54321"} *)
stringColumn2[str2, {-8, -1, 1}]
 (* {"n/A","abcdefgh","n/A"} *)
```

EDIT: For "rectangular" strings (strings with equal size substrings seperated by `"\n"`):

```
 ClearAll[stringColumn3];
 stringColumn3[strng_String, column_] := 
     StringTake[StringSplit[strng, "\n"], column]
```

Usage examples:

```
str3 = "ABCDEF 
abcdef 
1234567";

stringColumn3[str3, {2}]
 (* {"B","b","2"} *)
stringColumn3[str3, 2]
 (* {"AB","ab","12"} *)
stringColumn3[str3, -3]
 (* {"EF ","ef ","567"} *)
stringColumn3[str3, {-3}]
 (* {"E","e","5"} *)
stringColumn3[str3, {2, 5}]
 (* {"BCDE","bcde","2345"} *)
stringColumn3[str3, {2, 6, 2}]
 (* {"BDF","bdf","246"} *)
stringColumn3[str3, {-1, -5, -2}]
 (*  {" EC"," ec","753"} *)
stringColumn3[str3, {-1, 1, -1}]
 (* {" FEDCBA"," fedcba","7654321"} *)
```

Comment: If you have a rectangular array with column entries separated by spaces how would you extract columns then? For instance, if you have the text as:

    $1991 \ 12 \ 10 \\
     1992 \ 134  \ 14 \\
     1993 \ 15 \ 15$

and doing something like stringColumn[2] would give {12, 134, 15}